# past simple and past continuous in this context

Tags: past-tense, past-simple, past-continuous

which one is correct?

> "when I got the job offer **I was still working** in my old company, which I'd worked for 7 years"
>
> "when I got the job offer **I still worked** in my old company, which I'd worked for 7 years"

if they are both correct, what is the difference?

Comment: *...which I'd worked **for for** seven years.* You need the first preposition there because you worked ***for** the company*, AND you need the second one because you worked there ***for** seven years*. As to your *actual* question, ***I was still working*** is more likely (for the "ongoing, continuous" context), but ***I still worked*** is perfectly valid, and wouldn't really convey any different meaning.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica which one do you recommend for formal use like a resume or an interview etc.? and thank you I really appreciate your help.

Comment: The first is much more natural English (but I would suggest _where I had worked for seven years_).